# Shift characters in a string

Tags: code-golf, string

In this challenge, you are required to shift characters in an inputted string n number of times and output the shifted string

## Input

Input will first contain a string. In the next line, an integer, which denotes `n` will be present.

## Output

- If `n` is positive, shift the characters in the string to the right `n` times.
- If `n` is negative, shift the characters in the string to the left `n` times.
- If `n` is zero, don't shift the characters in the string.

After shifting (except when `n` is zero), print the shifted string.

## Notes

- The string will not be empty or `null`.
- The string will not be longer than 100 characters and will only contain ASCII characters in range (space) to `~`(tilde) (character codes 0x20 to 0x7E, inclusive). See [ASCII table](http://c10.ilbe.com/files/attach/new/20150514/377678/1372975772/5819899987/f146bf39e73cde248d508e5e1b534865.gif) for reference.
- The shift is cyclic.
- The number `n` may be positive, negative, or zero.
- `n` will always be greater than or equal to -1000 and lesser than or equal to 1000
- You may take input via `stdin` or from command line arguments
- The shifted string must be outputted in the `stdout` (or closest equivalent)
- You may write a full program or a function which takes input and outputs the string in `stdout` or closest equivalent

## Test Cases

1)

```
Hello world!
5             -->orld!Hello w
```

2)

```
Testing...
-3            -->ting...Tes
```

3)

```
~~~
1000          -->~~~
```

4)

```
12345
0             -->12345
```

5)

```
ABA
17            -->BAA
```

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest submission (in bytes) wins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Pyth, 4 bytes

```
.>zQ
```

This is almost similar to [my CJam 5 byte version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51020/38214), except that Pyth as a auto-eval input operator `Q`.

```
.>              # Cyclic right shift of 
  z             # Input first line as string
   Q            # Rest of the input as evaluated integer
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.%3EzQ&input=Testing...%0A-3&debug=0)

Comment: Exactly the same solution as [this](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges#comment15214_5336) :-)

Comment: @CoolGuy Its pretty straight forward. Though, I did not see this in sandbox..

Comment: Seems to no longer work for some reason. [Here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.%3E.%2a&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22Hello+world%21%22%2C5%0A%22Testing...%22%2C-3%0A%22~~~%22%2C1000%0A%2212345%22%2C0%0A%22ABA%22%2C17&debug=0)'s a working alternative, also 4 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript (*ES5*), <strike>55</strike> 52 bytes

```js
p=prompt;with(p())p(slice(b=-p()%length)+slice(0,b))
```

**Commented:**

```js
p = prompt; // store a copy of prompt function for reuse
with(p()) // extend scope chain with first input
    p( // print result
        slice(b = -p() % length) // take second input negated and modulo length
        +                        // and slice string by result
        slice(0, b) // concatenate with opposite slice
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 5 bytes

```
llim>
```

This is pretty straight forward.

```
l               e# Read the first line
 li             e# Read the second line and convert to integer
   m>           e# Shift rotate the first string by second integer places
```

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=llim%3E&input=Testing...%0A-3)

Comment: Would this fall under built-in functions?

Comment: @LegionMammal978 It *is* a built in function. But OP does not restrict the usage of built ins

Comment: Built-in functions are [standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1078/33208).

Comment: @LegionMammal978 you point to an answer which has almost 50-50 up/down votes. That is not a community decision.

Answer (score 2):

## C, 93 bytes

```
main(a,v,n)char**v;{a=v[2]-v[1]-1;n=atoi(v[2]);a=a*(n>0)-n%a;printf("%s%.*s",v[1]+a,a,v[1]);}
```

More clear is the function-argument version that was modified to make the command line-argument version

```
f(s,n,c)char*s;{c=strlen(s);c=c*(n>0)-n%c;printf("%s%.*s",s+c,c,s);}
```

This one is only 68 bytes, which just goes to show how disadvantaged C is when dealing with command line arguments.

If the shift, `n`, is positive then `strlen(s)-n%strlen(s)` is the offset and if `n` is negative the offset is `-n%strlen(s)`. The `printf` prints from the offset, `c`, to the end of the string, and then the final `c` characters from the beginning.

Examples:

```
$ ./rotstr "Hello world!" 5
orld!Hello w
$ ./rotstr "Testing..." -3
ting...Tes
$ ./rotstr "~~~" 1000
~~~
$ ./rotstr "12345" 0
12345
$ ./rotstr "ABA" 17
BAA
$ ./rotstr "Hello world!" -16
o world!Hell
```

Comment: It doesn't work as expected for me. When `v[2]` is `"1"`, the code simply outputs the string without any modifications. And only `"~~~"` and `"12345"` works. The rest of them gives wrong outputs. If they all rotated one more time, it would have been correcet.

Comment: I've tested it with both gcc and (with a slight modification `main(a,v,n)` -> `n;main(a,v)`) clang on linux and it works as expected. For gcc I'm using version 5.1.0 and compiling with `gcc -o rotstr rotstr.c`. What compiler are you using?

Comment: Tried making `n` global too. Same issue. I compiled using `gcc file.c -o file`. I'm using GCC 4.8.1 on windows. Is there any undefined behavior in your code?

Comment: Replacing `v[2]-v[1]-1` with `strlen(v[1])` might make a difference, that's the only place I can think of something subtle going on. Unfortunately I don't have access to a windows machine to test.

Comment: Yes. The code worked when I changed that.

Comment: Works fine for me. You can save 4 bytes by swapping the first two assignments and using a post-increment operator in `atoi`: `main(a,v,n)char**v;{n=atoi(v++[2]);a=v[1]-*v-1;a=a*(n>0)-n%a;printf("%s%.*s",*v+a,a,*v);}`

Comment: The problem may be some alignment/padding on the stack. Replacing `v[1]-*v-1` with `strlen(*v)` (in my version) solves that at the cost of 1 char.

Answer (score 2):

## K, <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
{|x!|y}
```

There is already a primitive "rotate" (`!`) which performs a generalization of this operation for lists. K strings are lists of characters, so it applies. The spec favors CJam and Pyth a bit, though, because K's rotate happens to go the opposite direction of what is desired. Wrapping `!` in a function and negating the implicit argument `x` will do what we want:

```
  f:{(-x)!y}
{(-x)!y}
  f[5;"Hello world!"]
"orld!Hello w"
  f[-3;"Testing..."]
"ting...Tes"
  f[17;"ABA"]
"BAA"
```

A slightly shorter approach, suggested by kirbyfan64sos, is to do away with the parentheses and negation in favor of reversing the string (`|`) before and after the rotation.

If it weren't for this impedance mismatch, the solution would be simply

```
!
```

Called identically:

```
  f:!
!
  f[5;"Hello, World!"]
", World!Hello"
  f[-5;"Hello, World!"]
"orld!Hello, W"
  f[0;"Hello, World!"]
"Hello, World!"
```

Comment: Would reversing the string with `|`, rotating that, and reversing it again yield the same result? If so, you can cut off a character.

Comment: Good point! That would work.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 45 bytes

```
s=input();n=int(input());print(s[-n:]+s[:-n])
```

The core of the program is

```
s[-n:]+s[:-n]
```

All the rest is just clumsy work with I/O.

Comment: This fail for the last `ABA 17` test case, and would in general if `|n| > length of string`

Comment: if you use `n=int(input())%len(s);`, it would work for integers greater than the string length, but require 7 more characters

Answer (score 2):

## Casio Basic, 27 bytes

```
StrRotate s,s,-n:Print s
```

As it turns out, there's a built-in for this on the Casio ClassPad! But it works in reverse, hence `-n`.

24 bytes for the code, 3 bytes to specify `s,n` as arguments.

Answer (score 1):

## Pip, 10 bytes

This could quite possibly be improved further. Still, for a language with no shift operator, 10 bytes ain't bad.

```
a@_M-b+,#a
```

Explanation:

```
            a, b are command-line args (implicit)
       ,#a  range(len(a))
    -b+     range(-b, len(a)-b)
a@_M        map(lambda x: a[x], range(-b, len(a)-b))
            Concatenate the list and print (implicit)
```

It works because string and list indexing in Pip is cyclical: `"Hello"@9 == "Hello"@4 == "o"`.

Answer (score 1):

## [rs](https://github.com/kirbyfan64/rs), 180 chars

```
^(-\d+) (.*)/\1 \2\t
+^(-\d+) (.)(.*?)\t(.*)$/\1 \3\t\2\4
^(-\d+) \t/\1 
^(-?)(\d+)/\1 (_)^^(\2)
+_(_*) (.*)(.)$/\1 \3\2
^- /- \t
+^- (.*?)\t(.*?)(.)$/- \1\3\t\2
^-? +/
\t/
```

[Live demo](http://kirbyfan64.github.io/rs/index.html?script=%5E(-%5Cd%2B)%20(.*)%2F%5C1%20%5C2%5Ct%0A%2B%5E(-%5Cd%2B)%20(.)(.*%3F)%5Ct(.*)%24%2F%5C1%20%5C3%5Ct%5C2%5C4%0A%5E(-%5Cd%2B)%20%5Ct%2F%5C1%20%0A%5E(-%3F)(%5Cd%2B)%2F%5C1%20(_)%5E%5E(%5C2)%0A%2B_(_*)%20(.*)(.)%24%2F%5C1%20%5C3%5C2%0A%5E-%20%2F-%20%5Ct%0A%2B%5E-%20(.*%3F)%5Ct(.*%3F)(.)%24%2F-%20%5C1%5C3%5Ct%5C2%0A%5E-%3F%20%2B%2F%0A%5Ct%2F%0A&input=5%20Hello%20world!%0A-3%20Testing...%0A0%2012345).

Most of this is reversing the string if the input number is negative. I took advantage of the fact that only some ASCII characters are valid input and used the tab to my advantage.

Note that I had to cheat a little: since rs is a single-line text modifier, I had to use `<number> <text>` as the input format.

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 167

```
enum S{;public static void main(String[]r){int n=-Integer.parseInt(r[1]),l=r[0].length();while(n<0)n+=l;n%=l;System.out.print(r[0].substring(n)+r[0].substring(0,n));}}
```

Takes the input through the command line.

funny enough, originally I had accidentally reversed how the string was supposed to be shifted. But fixing that mistake was shorter to just multiply n by -1 then to write the logic properly.

expanded:

```
enum Shift{
    ;
    public static void main(String[]args){
        int n=-Integer.parseInt(args[1]),length=args[0].length();
        while(n<0)n+=length;
        n%=length;
        System.out.print(args[0].substring(n)+args[0].substring(0,n));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `enum S{; ... }`?

Comment: I opted to write the full program because 9 bytes wasn't really going to make a huge difference. Also it's a reminder when I look back to prefer 
    enum S{;...}
over
    class S{...}
because (even though they take up the same number of bytes in this example) if I ever need to have an instance of the class, it takes one byte more with the enum version:
enum S{X;...}. This helps if I want to declare a method or variable in the class without having to use the static keyword or explictly instantiating a new object of the class.

Comment: Wow! Nice. Never knew that `enum`s can be used like this!

Comment: I know it's been close to two years since you've posted this, but you can golf a few things. `Integer.parseInt` can be `new Integer` (-5 bytes); and `n%=l;` can be removed if you change `r[0].substring(n)+` to `r[0].substring(n%=l)+` (-2 bytes). Also, you might want to specify this is Java 6, because in Java 7 or higher an enum with `main`-method isn't possible anymore.

Comment: too lazy to bother edit, but duely noted for the savings.

Comment: you seem to be wrong about enum and main. I just ran a hello world using main inside an enum on java 8. it worked.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP>=7.1, 88 Bytes

```php
for([,$s,$t]=$argv;$t;)$s=$t<0?substr($s,1).$s[!$t++]:$s[-1].substr($s,!$t--,-1);echo$s;
```

[Testcases](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b15ce8226741b555d6d2a1f7e67062ed8a13dc75)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 2 bytes

```
éV
```

[Try it online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=6VY=&input=IkhlbGxvIFdvcmxkISIsNQ==)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>6</s> <s>5</s> 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
(._
```

Inputs in the order `integer,string`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fQy/@/39dY66Q1OKSzLx0PT09AA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWVC8X8Nvfj/Ov@jo011lDxSc3LyFcrzi3JSFJVidaJ1jXWUQlKLSzLz0vX09EAihgYGBjpKdXV1IA6QZWhkbGIKljDXUXJ0clSKjQUA).

**Explanation:**

```python
(    # Negate the first (implicit) input-integer
 ._  # Rotate the second (implicit) input-string that many times towards the left
     # (which supports negative integers as rotating right instead)
     # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), <s>6</s> 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```python
sg+FÁ
```

Inputs in the order `integer,string`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/OF3b7XDj//@6xlwhqcUlmXnpenp6AA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWWCS9H/4nRtt8ON/2t1/kdHm@ooeaTm5OQrlOcX5aQoKsXqROsa6yiFpBaXZOal6@npgUQMDQwMdJTq6upAHCDL0MjYxBQsYa6j5OjkqBQbCwA).

**Explanation:**

```python
s      # Swap so the two (implicit) inputs are in reversed order on the stack
 g     # Pop and push the length of the top input-string
  +    # Add it to the input-integer
   F   # Loop that many times
    Á  #  And rotate once towards the right during every iteration
       #  (using the last implicit input-string in the first iteration)
```

Since the legacy version of 05AB1E only has builtins for *Rotate once towards the right/left*, and not *Rotate \$n\$ amount towards the right/left*, I loop \$length + input\$ amount of times and rotate that many times towards the right.

For example:

- `"Testing..."` and `-3` will rotate \$10 + -3 = 7\$ times towards the right, resulting in `ting...Tes`.
- `"Hello world"` and `5` will rotate \$11 + 5 = 16\$ times towards the right, resulting in `worldHello`.

The new version of 05AB1E does have a builtin for rotating \$n\$ amount of times towards the left, which is `._`, saving 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage).

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 31 bytes

```julia
s|n=String(circshift([s...],n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZBPa8QgEMXPzad4SA4KNmR3@@dQAk1OvW9vpYfEmKytmKIuZaHkq6ejZU/1oPN@Mw/m@XG2pn/YtvDjmmP0xs1cGa/CyUyRv4Wqqt6lE2I7B2qh64OuXnWIxXOkO@gIdkyjF6iTVp@BYdCzcSgATIsHDxJOwgsQ5Jy9aGsXfC/ejkziIMGoukImZPL9P5z1gxr1NJPndk@mLPqBDNRb15X4rq5r6iSR6W5/uLsnnuBfnXHbtWn4kWjXtkyIAjc5C/gXpY/WcVYG5Px6xHBB6dA0KD0TT6BfSsKLtKd2Y3quNlEQ2H4B)

Answer (score 1):

### Pascal (ISO standard 10206, “Extended Pascal”), 120 Bytes

```pascal
program p(input,output);var s:string(100);n:integer;begin read(s,n);n:=(-n)mod length(s);writeLn(subStr(s,n+1),s:n)end.
```

Ungolfed:

```pascal
program shiftCharactersInAString(input, output);
var
    line: string(100);
    n: integer;
begin
    read(line, n);
    { In Pascal, the result of the `mod` operation is non-negative. }
    n := (-n) mod length(line);
    { In Pascal, string indices are 1‑based. }
    writeLn(subStr(line, n + 1), line:n)
    { `line:n` is equivalent to `subStr(line, 1, n)` (if `n` ≤ `length(line)`). }
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 40 bytes

```
StringJoin@RotateRight[Characters@#,#2]&
```

```
StringJoin@RotateLeft[Characters@#,-#2]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2ar8D@4pCgzL90rPzPPISi/JLEkNSgzPaMk2jkjsSgxuSS1qNhBWUfZKFbtfwBQXUl0WrSSR2pOTr5CeX5RToqiko6CaWysNRdcMiS1uARonp6eHlBK1xhFrq6uTknH0MDAAEXU0MjYxFRJB1XQ0ckRqNQcJPYfAA)

Answer (score 1):

### [vemf](https://github.com/selaere/vemf), 1 byte

```
+
```

Left argument is string, right argument is offset.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 1 byte

```
ǔ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLHlCIsIiIsIjVcbkhlbGxvIHdvcmxkISJd)

Takes the number then the string. Prepend `$` if you want the inputs the other way round.

Built-in solution for "rotate right". Rotation is modular so we don't have to worry about negative inputs.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Code-page)

```
N⁴ṙ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/vUeOWhztn/v//3/S/B1AoX0chPL8oJ0URAA)

##### Explanation

```python
N⁴ṙ  # Main link. Takes an integer on the
     # left and a string on the right.
 ⁴   # Get the right argument (the string)
  ṙ  # And rotate it left by ↓ spaces
N    # The left argument negated
     # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 35 bytes

```python
lambda s,n:s[(x:=-n%len(s)):]+s[:x]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=Tc8xTsMwFAbgPaf4aYVqUztKaSsqS0FKJw7AFjIUNYFIrlPFRpQlF2GJhOBO3KRjnRcP9WL5_z8_6X3_Hb_ce2P6nyp9-f1wldz8T_Xu8LrfwQqjbM5OKpXmVpeGWc5VMbe5OhWBnl1pnUWKPALY5KnUusFn0-r9zURgzQUwhZSPoCjURJ_9x9q8xXHsoVwOMtAQe0Cw6zovFkmSkKEzQt-QWNwvV2tvrkAQ1JDJttkw5eGKBLPNsqiIoqppoWtTojagpRSObW0cG0KBmaczgYrdDW_Ox_37frwv)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `J`, \$ 8 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 6.58 bytes

```
LR_z0sAI
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_abSSl1LsgqWlJWm6Fit8guKrDIodPSFcqOiC9R6pOTn5Ogrh-UU5KYpcphBhAA)

No shift operator in Thunno so we have to do it ourselves.

##### Explanation

```python
LR_z0sAI  # Implicit input        STACK: "Hello, World!", 5
LR        # Length range          STACK: 5, [0..12]
  _       # Swapped subtract      STACK: [-5..7]
   z0     # First input           STACK: [-5..7], "Hello, World!"
     sAI  # Swap and index        STACK: ['o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '!', 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ',', ' ', 'W']
          # J flag joins          STACK: "orld!Hello, W"
          # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 2 bytes

```
|)
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%7C%29&i=%22Hello+world%21%22+5%0A%22Testing...%22+-3%0A%22%7E%7E%7E%22+1000%0A%2212345%22+0%0A%22ABA%22+17&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 0):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-palF`, 26 bytes

```perl
$_=substr$_.$_,@F-<>%@F,@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3ra4NKm4pEglXk8lXsfBTdfGTtXBDcj4/98jNScnX6E8vygnRZHLlCsktbgkMy9dT0@PS9eYq66ujsvQwMCAy9DI2MSUy4DL0cmRy9Cc619@QUlmfl7xf92CxBw3AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 28 bytes

```ruby
->s,n{s.chars.rotate(-n)*""}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhZ7dO2KdfKqi_WSMxKLivWK8ksSS1I1dPM0tZSUaiFKbroWlJYUK7hFK3mk5uTkK5TnF-WkKCrpKJjGcsFkQlKLSzLz0vX09IDiusYICUMjYxNToJhBLMSwBQsgNAA)

Answer (score 0):

### HP‑41C series, 4 Bytes

Input string is located in alpha register and number to rotate on top of the stack (i. e. the X register).
An extended functions module or HP‑41CX is required.

```
CHS     1 Byte   flip sign because AROT acts just the opposite as required
AROT    2 Bytes  rotate alpha register according to value in X register
AVIEW   1 Byte   display contents of alpha register
```